# Why is it necessary to 'manually' evaluate or cast an object's type at all?

Tags: c#, object, types, .net-4.0, casting

By manually, I mean code as though I needed to cater for as though the object isn't what I'd expect it to be.

For example, I'm working with a repeater. And as part of that I'm manipulating the DataSource property. To do this, I'm having to check the following first:

```
this.DataSource as List<MyObject>
```

This will return null if it's not a List of MyObject objects. If I cast it, and it isn't a List of MyObject objects, it will throw an exception.

This implies that it is known at that point whether it is a List of MyObject objects or not.

**Question**

So why not just allow me to code with this.DataSource as thought it already was the type that it is known to be? Like:

```
this.DataSource.First().Member
```

There's obviously no rhetoric in this question, and I'm not implying I should be able to do this, I'm genuinely interested in the answer.

Comment: This is a question about language design ("why is the language just this way?"), and I think it is valid.

Comment: I obviously agree. I fully appreciate how, at runtime, the framework can't perform any type of operation at all specific to a particular type if the type of an object is not known. I'm merely asking why it is this way.

Comment: May be helpful to know that _two_ types can be associated with a variable (or property value). The _compile-time_ type of the variable is the type the variable has in the program you are writing. That type is known when you type your code. Hold the mouse over the variable name, and a tool-tip will come up showing the compile-time type. The _run-time_ type is the actual type of the object instance that is present when the program runs. The run-time type will often be more "derived" than the compile-time type. In your case, compile-time type is `object`, while run-time type is `List<MyObject>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C# is a statically typed language. This is intentional. Static typing has benefits for maintainability, tooling, performance and probably other aspects as well.

In a dynamically typed language you could indeed write such code. The C# language could indeed be defined like this, but it was chosen not to be.

The trade-off between static and dynamic typing is complex, and I cannot fully elaborate on it in this answer. It has been extensively discussed on the web in many places.

Starting with C# 4 you can force dynamic semantics as well:

```
dynamic ds = this.DataSource;
Console.WriteLine(ds.First().Member); //compiles and works or fails at runtime
```

I recommend, that you harness the power of static typing as much as possible. `dynamic` is more of an escape hatch for special circumstances.

Comment: c# was a statically typed language before c#4.0. There after it can behave statically typed as well as dynamically typed(System.Dynamic)

Comment: Well, That was missing earlier. and now perfect. +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

Because [`Repeater.DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is defined as an `object`, the most basic class there is.

The compiler doesn't know what specific type you put in there, so if you want statically-typed access to it, you need to cast it.

Comment: But supposing I were allowed to access DataSource as though it were the List I was expecting it to be, why would it not raise an exception at that point but, initially, allow me to do so?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Why you give link to `Repeater.DataSource`? I can't find asp tag or something else.

Comment: @Eugene: second line of the question: _"For example, I'm working with a repeater. And as part of that I'm manipulating the DataSource property"_.